Efficient Interval Storage Using C++ Standard Library
I am working on a problem where each pair represents a closed interval, and I need a data structure to store a collection of these pairs. This data structure should support two operations: insert(pair) and delete(idx). The insert operation needs to check if the interval to be inserted overlaps with any existing intervals in the collection; if there is an overlap, the insertion should fail and return -1. The delete operation should remove the idx-th largest pair in the collection.
My goal is to implement this using only the C++ Standard Library, while keeping the code as minimal as possible. Additionally, it is crucial that both the insert and delete methods have a time complexity smaller than O(log n).
I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or ideas you might have on how to achieve this efficiently, without the need for coding. Thank you very much for your assistance! So far, the only solution I have come up with is using a B+ tree, but it requires a little much of code.
class CustomDataStructure {
// some underlying private data structures
public:
    bool insert(const pair<int ,int>& interval);
    pair<int ,int> delete(unsigned int idx); // return deleted interval
}

Here is an example workflow of this class:
original intervals:

call insert({4,10});

call delete(2);


"but it requires too much code.": you have a code size limit? Why? And what is it?

Thank you for pointing out the issue, I apologize for any confusion. I have revised the question!

its still a bit vague. sometimes you can make progress by showing your code and asking about one specific detail. If you are lucky this will get you going also with the bigger picture. And if not you have at least one more detail solved and can continue with the next

its still unclear what you mean with "but it reqiures a little much of code" or why this is an issue. To get something done in programming you need code.

@trincot It's part of an online coding contest ended a few days ago, and I haven't found a simple solution yet.  just need the algorithm to be as straightforward as possible

You can check all the available stl containers on the web, choose what suits your needs the most and then wrap it around with your constraints. Because of O(log n) requirement array like containers out of the game and if deletion happens quite frequently it should be sorted.

Do you want source code to be minimal or do you want the compiled code to be minimal. (you could use a std::vector and do some moving of intervals to keep them sorted, that is not much code, but also maybe not performant enough?)

What do you mean by "idx-th largest pair"?

@Pepijn Kramer thanks for your comment! I just need the source code to be minimal

Side note : do NOT use std::pair to represent an interval just add a new struct with two members. std::pair is to be used in template programming where the pair has no semantic meaning (yet).

@kiner_shah thanks for your comment! Since none of the intervals overlap, the "idx-th largest pair" refers to the position of the interval on the number line.

@b39b332d And why do you think minimal source code is important? You can still make a custom datastructure and then use that in your final code.

Better to give an example for "idx-th largest pair".

@Pepijn Kramer thanks for your reply! because the only souce that I can include is stl and some standard C++11 library like  and  etc.

@kiner_shah thanks for your reply! I will try to include a diagram at the end of the question

"I just need the source code to be minimal": please provide a metric for that. What is minimal? The shortest ever possible code? That is offtopic. Then how short? You have a number of characters as limit?

@trincot Sorry for the confusion, it's hard to describe. First, it needs to require less code than implementing a B+ tree, and beyond that, the less code, the better.

So you mean, AVL, red-black, skiplist, ..etc? Did you try?

Let me ask it differently: how large was your B+tree implementation (#lines), and what is the maximum that is acceptable to you? Are you sure your B+ implementation could not be written with less code?

Could you store the intervals in the form of an ordered set of integers, with twice as many integers as intervals. Even indexed integer being starts and odd indexed integers being ends of intervals. Then removing the ith interval would be removing both the 2i and 2i+1 th elements from the set?

There is no container in std that can satisfy your requirements.
None of the sequence containers can insert into arbitrary positions in less than O(size()). vector, deque and inplace_vector have O(size) insert. list and forward_list have O(size) lookup.
None of the associative or unordered associative containers can find the ith index in less than O(i). std::advance et.al. are O(i) unless the iterator satisfies RandomAccessIterator, which isn't the case for those containers.
None of the container adaptors help, because they still have the insertion characteristics of the underlying container.
You'd need to implement your own container to reach your complexity requirements. Something like an Indexable Skip List would work.

Did you ever consider standard associative classes family?

@Red.Wave yes, see paragraph 3

Then you can do it  many different ways. A std::set of pairs with custome comparator is one of many. This answers is pushing OP towards high risk alternatives.

Thanks for your advice! If the containers in the STL library and their combinations aren't sufficient to solve the problem, maybe an Indexable Skip List is the easiest data structure to implement.

@Red.Wave did you read the complexity requirements? There is no way to get to the ith element of a std::set in logarithmic time

A binary tree is supposed to find any value in O(log n) and insertion/deletion is O(n). So what's the point in not wanting the simplest implementation through std::set?

@Red.Wave finding an element matching a key is O(log n). The requirement is finding the element at position i, which is O(n). You can augment a balanced tree with index data, but that isn't what the std containers do.

Only assuming the OP literally meant access by index. I doubt that was more than a bad composition of question by SB not too deeply involved with C++. Then again I would at least give a hint on std::flat_set.

@Red.Wave To be precise, being able to find any value in O(log n) is a property of a balanced binary search tree. Insertion and deletion in a BBST are also O(log n), not O(n). To get O(log n) access by index, GCC's policy based data structures can be used, among which is an implementation of augmented balanced binary search trees that store subtree size information.

@Red.Wave see para 4 about flat_set

skip lists are better than balanced trees for this operation since they support sequential traversal. Though a B+ tree would also but is much harder to implement. A 2-3 Tree variant would implement this scenario quite easily as well.

std::set provides the solution. This answer is wrong. See @Thibe's solution below.

@AminM it doesn't meet the complexity requirements set out in the question, as I explain.

well then to do that you'd need 2 sets. One that does what Thibe's solution does. And one that is ordered by size. What I'd do is store each range in an unordered vector, then store it's vector index in both sets, where one uses the index to sort by range (like Thibe's solution) the other by size. Lazy delete to avoid linear deletion.

@AminM Can you elaborate on "Lazy delete"? You keep saying that it solves the problem of linear deletion from a set, but the linear part is identifying the element to delete, not the removal of it.

No because you can use the set to find the index to the vector where the element is. You store indices in the set, not objects.

@AminM and how do you identify the element, in the index container, to delete? Is "lazy delete" simply not removing elements from the object vector, and orphaning them with the index container? Because that still doesn't meet the complexity requirement afaict

you overload the comparison operator in the sets to use the found index to retrieve the values from the vector.
To delete you delete the object from both sets (also learning the index) and mark the position in the vector as "deleted" (using the index you found). Deletion is O(logN). But some garbage collection will be needed at times (for example when expanding the size of the vector for new items). If you find that intolerable keep a list of free indices as well. Then when a space is freed you can reuse it and not need to grow the vector until absolutely necessary.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is partially similar as peterchen's answer:
The best I can think of is

an std::set for the binary search and insert by key
with a custom 'less' compare function which is configured to the container like std::set<my_pair, my_compare>.

The comparison is as simple as bool my_compare(const my_pair& left, const my_pair& right){ return left.high < right.low; }
The custom comparison treats all pairs with same or overlaping ranges as equal.
'A' neither less than 'B' nor 'B' less than 'A' means 'A' and 'B' are treated the same.
Then you only need to check the iterator returned from std::set::insert to see if a range exists.
auto it = mySet.insert(interval);
if(it.second)
{
    // success
}
else
{
    if(*it.first == interval)
    {
        // exact match
    }
    else
    {
        // must be a range overlap
    }
}

For the deletion you can use the std::set::reverse_iterator and a for-loop to count from 0 to idx.  This makes the deletion O(N), but N depends only on the index and not on the  size of the std::set (unless the index depends on the total size of the std::set).
Watch out: To use the reverse iterator for std::set::erase it needs to be converted to a forward iterator like mySet.erase(std::next(it).base())

Provide the comparator and feed it to std::set<my_pair, my_compare>. Don't try to specialize std::less. Then if result of a query into set is equal to original value(using ordinary comparison), the range exists, otherwise overlaps. Add more meat with better code snippets.

Thanks for the good input to my very first answer.

I made some adoptions. I agree that specializing std::less` can affect more than just the sorted container.

That would be good enough. I wish I were in shoes to accept it.

Let's learn from Database Relationship Theory.
Use std::vector to hold the data.  This will be the main table.
Use std::map<key, vector-index> as an index table.
You lookup the vector index using the index table, then use the vector index to directly access the data.

I'm a little bit confused. Could you please elaborate on how std::map achieves O(log N) time complexity for the insert method?I'm wondering because the idx (might be the key of std::map in your answer) of any intervals might change with each insert call.

vector still has linear insert and erase

You can lazy delete on the vector to avoid linear time problems.

In practice:

Use a sorted vector, ensure that isnert keeps it sorted
sort by start of interval
insert uses std::lower_bound, comparing start of interval, to find the insert positon (O log N).
Check for overlap with the found item and the one after that.  (O 1)

Insert at the given position if there is no conflict (O(1) for the list, O(N) for vector - but in many practical situations, the latter may still be faster.)
In theory: use std::map instead. Satisfies Big-O, but for that element size it's likely slower when Big-O starts to matter.

You can "cheapen" erasure by tagging intervals as "unused"; e.g., by making them equivalent to length 0. This means insert has to check more than just the immediate successor, but it's still somewhere around amortized O(1) except for worst-case workloads.

inserting in the middle of a vector, array or deque is O(N). You can't binary search a list or forward_list.

Thanks for your suggestion! however, both vector and list make delete method has O(N) time complexity

@b39b332d correcct of course (I don't know why I read O(N log N) in your request, makes no sense but that stuck)
